# Name of pattern where an object is stored by UUID

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uuid

I am programming an application where I want to store Session information by a UUID. For this purpose, I wrote this code:

```py
import uuid

class ObjectStore:
  def __init__(self):
    self.objects = {}

  def add(self, obj):
    uuid_value = uuid.uuid4() # UUID4 generates a random UUID
    self.objects[uuid_value] = obj
    return uuid_value

  def retrieve(self, uuid):
    return self.objects[uuid]
```

Is this structure a common pattern? If so, does it have a name?

Comment: You mean other than a relational database table? It appears to be type of *cache*. But I am trying to understand this. The caller has a bunch of objects and for each one receives a `uuid` that maps to one of the objects and can be used to retrieve the object. Presumably the caller can then remove all references to the objects as long as he has a list of the `uuids`. But how does the caller know which `uuid` he wants to retrieve because a `uuid` carries no semantic meaning, unless he just wants all of them? But then what's the point? Can you describe a use case?

Comment: The object store contains sessions. Clients receive a session ID and potentially more information. If the client sends the ID back to the server I can look up what session data belongs to it.
The semantic meaning of the ID for the caller would be the place where it is stored. Normally, one would use a pointer or reference in such a use case, but that's not possible because the caller is a program that does not have (direct) access to the data.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in your post.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is an "opaque token"; that your token happens to be a UUID is an implementation detail.